# Children to children communication

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

My component is pretty big so I will give you simplified example, maybe someone will know how to solve my problem.

I have invoice component with children components like 'subtotal', 'vat_subtotal', 'total' (it's example). I'm using v-ref to get direct access to every child from invoice component. Also, subtotal is calculated from invoice properties, then vat_subtotal is calculated from subtotal children properties. And 'total' is calculated from vat_subtotal children.

Example:

```
invoice.$refs.subtotal.total = {some calculations}
vat_subtotal.total = @$parent.$refs.subtotal.total * 1.21
total.total = @$parent.$refs.vat_subtotal.total
```

The problem is that i'm getting warnings when page loads, be cause 'total' children is trying to access 'vat_total' children properties, but @$parent.$refs.vat_total is still 'undefined' (I don't know why. When later im changing something in form, it reacts normaly and recalculate everything right). It seems, that one children is trying to compute properties while other children isn't loaded yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you are trying to solve things is technically possible but highly discouraged. As stated in the [docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Parent-Child-Communication):

> Although it’s possible to access any instance in the parent chain, you should avoid directly relying on parent data in a child component and prefer passing data down explicitly using props. In addition, it is a very bad idea to mutate parent state from a child component, because:
>
> 1. It makes the parent and child tightly coupled;
> 2. It makes the parent state much harder to reason about when looking at it alone, because its state may be modified by any child! Ideally, only a component itself should be allowed to modify its own state.

In general, you should aim for creating a model representing the state of your application. Instead of accessing parents / children directly, pass any relevant data down to children using props. Children can notify their parent about changes using [events](https://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Custom-Events), or you can use [.sync](http://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Prop-Binding-Types) binding to synchronize models automatically.

I think that you would benefit from reading about more structured approach to Vue application architecture. I'd start with [Flux-inspired Application Architecture for Vue.js.](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex)

Comment: Well for the first bullet: they are tighly coupled. It's invoice with its subtotals. But I got it. The worst part that I have to describe every prop in parent component, then do same in each children (ofc only neccessary for that children). I took vuejs be cause I wanted to write less :)) Thank you for reference i will check it.

Comment: @KarolisTička On the other hand, it's simpler to refer to them: `vat_subtotal.total` instead of `@$parent.$refs.vat_subtotal.total`

Comment: You can pass objects as props, in which you can collect all the data properties you need to pass down.

Comment: Well, it's strange flow anyway. So childrens are only for templating and reuse? I can't store any props/data there if that data doesn't exist on parent instance? If i want to compute some props in children components, I have to define these props/attributes on parent instance and pass to children and sync them? It's repetitive code. Well, in the end of the day, I have two options, keep everything in my parent (huge model), or just define data attributes on parent, but sync and comput them on children.

Comment: Parent can pass whole object as one child property. In this way parent doesn't know a thing about the contents of this object. It is child responsibility to handle it on it's own.

Comment: So it's not recommended to change parent state (props/data) from child, but it's ok to do this if your prop is raw shared object? I'm talking about source of truth.

Comment: It doesn't really matter if you pass a raw object or set of properties down to a child. What matters is that a child shouldn't need to know its parents api. Let's say you have a person editor component with two props: first and last name. It so happens that a parent needs to display full name. Editor component only edits first and last name. Parent defines computed property fullName. In this way you can reuse your editor in multiple parents, not only those having fullName property....

Answer (score 3):

Don't reach into a child for data. If the parent needs access (in your case, to give access to another child), the data item should be created in the parent and passed as a `prop` to the child. That is how data can be shared among multiple children. Child components should not depend on other child components being available through the parent (or on anything in the parent, really, if it isn't passed in as a `prop`).

If the child component is responsible for changing the `prop` value, you can [pass it using `.sync`](http://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Prop-Binding-Types).

Comment: There are a lot of properties, thats why I wanted to split them over sub-components. But I got the point. Thank you.